# Android System Webview

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-source

I am looking into the AOSP source code to see how WebViews are implemented. As far as I know, with Android 6, WebView is now a separate application of its own (called Android System Webview). However, in the external/chromium-webview folder I only have the apk files.

I found frameworks/base/core/java/webkit/WebView.java, which seems to be the WebView implementation, but I don't quite understand if this is the real implementation or just a stub. Is it this one, or the source code on chromium website that actually is the Android System WebView?

Also, how is it that an Android app can use the Android System Webview app to create a Webview in itself? How are they connected?

Finally, in the folder where I have webview.apk, readme mentions libwebviewchromium.so. What is that?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I guess chromium is a separate project. They are building the apk and putting it in AOSP.

You should refer here-https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-android-webview

I ASSUME Web view is just a view...all the logic, parsing of html and other stuff is there in separate app...webview just binds to other app for all the logic...

Comment: Thanks, that helps. What I don't understand is how we can create a WebView in our apps even though now WebView seems to be a separate app. I don't understand the connection.

Comment: @Alice I ASSUME Web view is just a view...all the logic, parsing of html and other stuff is there in separate app...we view just binds to other app for all the logic...

Comment: That makes sense, but then how would you explain that WebView inherits the permissions of my own application?

Comment: sign the application with same key,have shared user id,make component permission type system|signature...there are different ways

Comment: Is there anyway to get the source code of the app called "Android System WebView"？

Comment: oh, I got it on Github. https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/android_webview/docs/aosp-system-integration.md